# Blender textures overlapping when baking from two to one texture

Tags: render, blender, roblox, fbx

I have a fbx which have two textures. One for the face and one for the body. I am trying to bake these two textures into one. This because I want to import the fbx to Roblox. But when I bake, the two textures is put on top of each other. I have tried to convert the newly baked object to a smart uv project, but the layers which are on top of each other just stay put. And the final texture then looks awful.

These are my steps:

1. I select the face object and add a new texture image. Which I call 'BakeTest'.
   [image]
2. Then I select the body object and copy the 'BakeTest' to this as well.
   [image]
3. I have now selected both object1 and object2. Now I bake.
   [image]
4. This is the result with the two original textures being on top of each other.
   [image]
5. I have tried to make this uv a smart project, but then it looks like this with the same background and all split up.
   [image]
6. How can I come pass this so all texture pieces live in harmony side by side so I can import only ONE texture for my object in Roblox :)

Thanks for any input on this matter!

Answer (score 0):

What appears to be happening is that your UV maps were overlapping before you baked them. To solve this, try using the "UV Smart Project" BEFORE you bake the textures. Also, set your island margin on the Smart Project to a number other than zero (I recommend 0.010) to give an extra boundary between the textures to prevent overlap.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, but I could not manage to change it to UV smart project before. It seemed like it already was. Btw this is the object: https://sketchfab.com/3d-models/simba-1383202bcf7b4d13af75f6f29aae7ed9